# HSQLDB bad Query performance and out of Memory

Tags: out-of-memory, relational-database, hsqldb, query-performance

I have a Question regarding my current project with HSQLDB.

I have a huge join which should give me a feedback about the selled amunt of different products in which region. The Statement works complety corect, but the performance is quite bad.

```
SELECT Verkaufsgebiet.verkaufsgebiet, Artikel.Artikel_Name, sum(Artikel_Liste.Menge)

FROM Artikel_Liste

JOIN Artikel ON Artikel_Liste.Artikel = Artikel.Artikel

JOIN Rechnung ON artikel_liste.rechnungsnummer = Rechnung.rechnungsnummer

JOIN Bearbeiter ON Rechnung.Bearbeiter = Bearbeiter.B_Bearbeiter_ID

JOIN Verkaufsgebiet ON Bearbeiter.b_verkaufsgebiet = Verkaufsgebiet.verkaufsgebiet_id

GROUP BY Artikel.Artikel_Name, Verkaufsgebiet.verkaufsgebiet
```

Explain Analyze:

```
isDistinctSelect=[false]
isGrouped=[true]
isAggregated=[true]
columns=[  COLUMN: PUBLIC.VERKAUFSGEBIET.VERKAUFSGEBIET nullable
  COLUMN: PUBLIC.ARTIKEL.ARTIKEL_NAME not nullable

  SUM  arg=[   COLUMN: PUBLIC.ARTIKEL_LISTE.MENGE
 nullable

]
[range variable 1
  join type=INNER
  table=ARTIKEL_LISTE
  cardinality=4000009
  access=FULL SCAN
  join condition = [index=SYS_IDX_ARTIKEL_LISTE_PK_10099
  ]
  ][range variable 2
  join type=INNER
  table=ARTIKEL
  cardinality=11
  access=INDEX PRED
  join condition = [index=SYS_IDX_ARTIKEL_PK_10093
    start conditions=[
    EQUAL arg_left=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.ARTIKEL.ARTIKEL
] arg_right=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.ARTIKEL_LISTE.ARTIKEL
]]
    end condition=[
    EQUAL arg_left=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.ARTIKEL.ARTIKEL
] arg_right=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.ARTIKEL_LISTE.ARTIKEL
]]
  ]
  ][range variable 3
  join type=INNER
  table=RECHNUNG
  cardinality=1332427
  access=INDEX PRED
  join condition = [index=SYS_IDX_RECHNUNG_PK_10120
    start conditions=[
    EQUAL arg_left=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.RECHNUNG.RECHNUNGSNUMMER
] arg_right=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.ARTIKEL_LISTE.RECHNUNGSNUMMER
]]
    end condition=[
    EQUAL arg_left=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.RECHNUNG.RECHNUNGSNUMMER
] arg_right=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.ARTIKEL_LISTE.RECHNUNGSNUMMER
]]
  ]
  ][range variable 4
  join type=INNER
  table=BEARBEITER
  cardinality=50
  access=INDEX PRED
  join condition = [index=SYS_IDX_BEARBEITER_PK_10108
    start conditions=[
    EQUAL arg_left=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.BEARBEITER.B_BEARBEITER_ID
] arg_right=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.RECHNUNG.BEARBEITER
]]
    end condition=[
    EQUAL arg_left=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.BEARBEITER.B_BEARBEITER_ID
] arg_right=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.RECHNUNG.BEARBEITER
]]
  ]
  ][range variable 5
  join type=INNER
  table=VERKAUFSGEBIET
  cardinality=5
  access=INDEX PRED
  join condition = [index=SYS_IDX_VERKAUFSGEBIET_PK_10129
    start conditions=[
    EQUAL arg_left=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.VERKAUFSGEBIET.VERKAUFSGEBIET_ID
] arg_right=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.BEARBEITER.B_VERKAUFSGEBIET
]]
    end condition=[
    EQUAL arg_left=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.VERKAUFSGEBIET.VERKAUFSGEBIET_ID
] arg_right=[     COLUMN: PUBLIC.BEARBEITER.B_VERKAUFSGEBIET
]]
  ]
  ]]
groupColumns=[COLUMN: PUBLIC.ARTIKEL.ARTIKEL_NAME
COLUMN: PUBLIC.VERKAUFSGEBIET.VERKAUFSGEBIET
]
PARAMETERS=[]
SUBQUERIES[]
```

My Questin is, how can i get a better performance of this query. For example i will run the Query with 4.000.000 of Data.

The HSQLDB runs on a Virtual Server with 2x vCPU Intel XEON E5540 2,53 GHz, 6GB RAM on an OpenSuse 11.4 Server with Openjdk-1.5, I know that is not the best Java version but i don't want to much trouble, in case of an upgrade, in the end of my final exam ;)

My Question is how can i get a better query performance as well?

And my Other Question how can i get more data into these database in Server Memory mode?

Currently I'm running out of Memory, if i try to get more 4.000.000 records into the database. The Server is started with -Xmx2048M Parameter, if i try to start with more RAM i'm not able to launch a JVM. They are using 2gb RAM for this dataset.

Is there any possibility to get a better RAM handling? Maybe with the CHECKPOINT Statement should that work?

Or is that simply the limit of the HSQLDB for me. I don't really want to have CACHED Tables, they should be stored in Memory as well.

Comment: The execution plan you are showing is for Postgres, not for HSQLDB. Which DBMS are you really using? Are there any indexes defined on the tables?

Comment: Hi Sry my mistake, i test the performance between Postgresql and HSQLDB and paste the wrong result. I fixed that. In Addition i don't use an Index except the primary and foreign Keys.

Comment: You should index all columns that are using in a join condition: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_index_speed (btw: your Postgres installation could benefit a lot from increasing `work_mem`)

Comment: thanks for the help, with the indexing, that is one of my next seps. i just want to check the good query performance for my hsqldb in the other hand the bad performance of my postgresql. This query is running in HSQLDB (35000ms)and Postgresql(207248ms) But in the other case it's completly twisted with the result.

Comment: Here is the other Statement, where the performance on Postgresql is about 600ms and for the HSQLDB 30000ms:SELECT count(*)

FROM Artikel_Liste

JOIN Artikel ON Artikel_Liste.Artikel = Artikel.Artikel

JOIN Rechnung ON artikel_liste.AL_rechnungsnummer = Rechnung.Artikel_liste

JOIN Kunde ON Rechnung.Kunde = Kunde.K_kdnr

JOIN Wohnort ON Kunde.wohnort_plz_id = Wohnort.plz_id

Where Wohnort.ort = 'Leipzig'

AND Artikel.Artikel_name = '0.5 Fanta'

Comment: To be honest: I would never expect HSQLDB to outperform Postgres - especially with larger databases.

Comment: that's my conclusion too. But I got this with the sum() statement. But the point is that HSQLDB promote the database as massdata tool. Too handle an huge amount of data and to be an In-Memory database. And at least the benchmark on the first site asy that it will be faster as a MYSQL with an INNODB implementation. And i found some Benchmark where Postgresql is quite slower than these Database. So i just tried to figure out what's going on here ;)

Comment: You posted the execution plan for the query that runs 6 times faster on HSQLDB than Postgresql but not the one that you say is 5 times slower? You will probably need to create one or two indexes and things will go very fast.